# Handling bad values when parsing function arguments in bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to handle bad values when parsing function arguments in bash.  What can I do?

Bad values for `-v` (not 1,2 or 3) makes the function go wrong when parsing arguments.

```
myfunc -v 1eo -g -W 3
```

Here is the code

```bsh
    while (( $# > 0 )); do
      opt="$1"
      case $opt in 
       ("-v"|"--verbiage")
           if [[ $2 == [1-3] ]]; then
             vb="$2" ; shift ; shift
           else
            vb=1 ; shift 1 
           fi
           ;;
       ("-g")
           glob_ptrn=1 ; shift 1 ;;
       (*) 
           break ;;
      esac 
    done
```

Comment: This is a stackoverflow question. Consider [using getopts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16496491/4970442) (with an s) `while getopts "v:g:W" options; do \ case "${options}" in` ...

Comment: I don't see any errors there. Run your script with bash -x and see which branch is executed.

Comment: How can I match an option argument starting with `-` but is not a negative number?

Comment: If I use `myfunc -v eo -g` arguments are only shifted by 1.